# How to get ul class name while clicking on li element

Tags: jquery

How to get ul class name while clicking li - jquery

```
<div class="div-class-parent">
    <div class="div-class">test</div>
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li class="node-205"></li>
        <li class="node-150"></li>
        <li class="node-160"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**EDITED:**

**For example when i clicking the "li" I need to get the class name of ul and class name of the div.**

That is i need the class name "tabs" and "div-class".

When i use the below code i get the parent class name of div that is i get "div-class-parent".

```
$('li').click(function() {
   alert($(this).closest('div').attr('class'));
});
```

How can this be done using jquery.

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply reference to the parent:

```
$('li').click(function() {
   alert($(this).parent().attr('class'));
});
```

or find closest element:

```
$('li').click(function() {
   alert($(this).closest('ul').attr('class'));
});
```

**EDIT**

```
$('li').click(function() {
   var $ul = $(this).closest('ul');
   alert($ul.attr('class')); // ul class
   alert($ul.prev().attr('class')); // div class
});
```

Comment: You can use `prev()` to get previous element near `ul`.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('li').click(function(){
    alert($(this).parent().attr('class'))
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/c03goo10/) simple fiddle.

**HTML**

```
<div class="div-class-parent">
    <div class="div-class">test</div>
    <ul class="tabs">
        <li class="node-205"></li>
        <li class="node-150"></li>
        <li class="node-160"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$("li").click(function(){
    alert($(this).parent().attr("class"));
    alert($(this).parent().prev().attr("class"));
});
```